# Why did the status of women in India decline?

Tags: india, women, ancient-india

If one looks at the present dynamic structure of Indian society one can see that though constantly changing, it still has in its heart many socio-cultural elements that can be traced by or said to have been originated in Ancient India, particularly the Vedic Ages.

One such example is the caste system (and its offshoot Jati system) which can be said to be a polluted version of the Varna system mentioned in the Rigveda. There are similarly other social institutions, roles, etc whose dynamics can be studied with reference to its historical form.

In light of this, I am trying to understand the social position of Indian women from a historical perspective. A surprising thing is that even though the historical (like Vedic period) philosophies and ideas like considering "Mother as greater than God" (in some Indian cultures) are still prevalent their social position has drastically changed.

My question is: Historically what went wrong with the status of Indian Women?

It was not like this from the beginning.

The following Wikipedia quote shows how in early Vedic era the status of women was high if not higher in some cases:

> Women during the Vedic period enjoyed high status with men in all aspects of life. Works by ancient Indian grammarians such as Patanjali and Katyayana suggest that women were educated in the early Vedic period.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice))[3] Rig Vedic verses suggest that women married at a mature age and were probably free to select their own husbands in a practice called [swayamvar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svayamvara) or live-in relationship called Gandharva marriage.[4] The Rig Veda and Upanishads mention several women sages and seers, notably Gargi Vachaknavi and Maitreyi

So, where did the problem start, and social evils like [Sati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice)), widow burning, and considering women as lowly and below men crept into the culture?

Did these practices start majorly due to the ideas of Manu, Aryabhatta, and their contemporaries, or were there other reasons (like the concept of Zeenans bought to India by invaders)?

Comment: I would think that the assumption that "the status of women in India declined" is too broad. You may want to focus specifically on some geographic region or culture.

Comment: I'd caution that the two things this question describes aren't as opposed as someone raised in the modern era might think. Arguably the lowest point for the legal status of women in western culture was around the Victorian era, but if you read their own words on the subject they idealized and celebrated women (in their traditional roles), and considered anyone allowing women more freedom or responsibility to be "degrading" them.

Comment: Women are, on average, more emotional than males. Also, it is not uncommon, regardless of gender, to desire one's death, while grieving someone's loss. As such, the *Sati* practice might not have initially meant to its original practitioners what the post suggests. For instance, the wife of a famous [contemporary Romanian poet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Augustin_Doinas) committed suicide by drowning, upon her husband's death. Needless to say, neither were ethnically or religiously Hindu.

Comment: @Lucian "Women are, on average, more emotional than males. Also, it is not uncommon, regardless of gender, to desire one's death, while grieving someone's loss. As such, the Sati practice might not have initially meant to its original practitioners what the post suggests." Takes some nerve to post that, esp. on International Women's Day.

Comment: @RedSonja: [Widowhood poses an increased risk for suicide](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.557.6929&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Note that other Asian populations have similar traditions, such as the south Indian [thalaikoothal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalaikoothal), or the Japanese *kamikaze* and *seppuku* or *hara-kiri* practices. Also, as far as suicide amongst the elderly is concerned, see [suicide in South Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_in_South_Korea) and [Greenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_in_Greenland).